# Groovy: How to check if a string contains any element of an array?

Tags: arrays, string, groovy

I have an array of strings `pointAddress` and I want to check each entry if it contains strings from another array, `validPointTypes`.

```
def pointAddress = ['bacnet://240101/AV:3', 'bacnet://240101/BV:9', 'bacnet://240101/AV:7', 'bacnet://240101/BALM:15']
def validPointTypes = ['AV', 'AI', 'AO', 'ANI', 'ANO', 'BV', 'BI', 'BO', 'BNI', 'BNO']
```

Right now I just have a giant `if` statement.

```
j = pointName.size()
for(j=j-1; j>=0;j--) {
    if(pointAddress[j]) {
        if(pointAddress[j].contains('AV') || pointAddress[j].contains('AI') || 
            pointAddress[j].contains('AO') || pointAddress[j].contains('ANI') || 
            pointAddress[j].contains('ANO') || pointAddress[j].contains('BV') || 
            pointAddress[j].contains('BI') || pointAddress[j].contains('BO') || 
            pointAddress[j].contains('BNI') || pointAddress[j].contains('BNO')) {
        } else {
            pointAddress.remove(j)
            pointName.remove(j)
            m++
        }
    } else {
        pointName.remove(j)
        m++
    }
}
```

There's gotta be a better way, right?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
def valid = pointAddress.findAll { a ->
    validPointTypes.any { a.contains(it) }
}
```

Should do it

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I went with `if(validPointTypes.any { pointAddress[j].contains(it) })` since I also had to remove entries from the `pointName` array. Me thinks I need to use a map instead of all these arrays.

Comment: The findAll should remove them from the result for you?

Comment: It does, works perfectly! I just needed to remove the corresponding pointName array entry as well.

Comment: Will this `contain()` can be tweaked somehow so that if I want to search for `fr` word in a list then it should not return/print/find `befr`? How can I make .contain() so that it can find a WHOLE word vs `.*word.*` (which actually contains true meaning is)

Comment: I can't use Groovy `matches()` as the word can be a list `[fr, ae, pt]` or just a word `fr` (as the parameter's selection type is Multiple choice in Jenkins Active choice plugin).