# Check if any element of array contains specified string in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069701/groovy-how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-any-element-of-an-array) which describes how to compare two arrays against one another very well. However, if I have some input string given from user like "20394875apple29038475" or "i love apples" and I want to check if any of the strings in a string array are present in the user given string regardless of upper/lower case, how can i do this in groovy?

Let's imagine the string array we are checking to have fruits like ("apple","banana","cherry").

In this case we would return true because the substring "apple" is present in the user given string "20394875apple29038475"

... I am thinking that the best way would be something like this?:

```
boolean fruitFound = false

for (item in fruitArray){
    if(usrResponse.contains(item)){
        responseFound = true
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy: How to check if a string contains any element of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069701/groovy-how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-any-element-of-an-array) - the same answer applies.

Comment: Actually its a different question as we are not comparing two different arrays and also trying to ignore the case of the strings @doelleri

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
fruitFound = fruitArray.any{usrResponse.contains(it)}
```

Comment: Thanks @Admiral_x Would this also ignoreCase ? So if the user types in "ApPLe" would it still find the match with fruitArray element of "I love a good apple" ?

Comment: you're welcome, no, it's case sensitive, you can do something like : fruitArray.any{usrResponse.toLowerCase().contains(it.toLowerCase())} to convert all the strings to lower case

Comment: this can also identify wheter if a ArrayList contains any keywords. I.e. check whether if `'a'` or '`e`' included in `['a', 'b', 'c']` : `['a', 'b', 'c'].any { ['a', 'e'].contains(it} }`

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
def fruits = ["apple","banana","cherry"]
def str = '20394875banana29038475'
assert fruits.findAll{str.contains(it)}.any{true}
```

EDIT: To ignore case

```
assert fruits.findAll{str.toLowerCase().contains(it.toLowerCase())}.any{true}
```

or

```
assert fruits*.toLowerCase().findAll{str.toLowerCase().contains(it)}.any{true}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rao . Would this also ignoreCase ? So if the user types in "ApPLe" would it still find the match with fruitArray element of "I love a good apple" ?